# Multidimensional fit and interpolation for scattered unstructured data

Tags: fitting, interpolation

I have data structured like `{{{i,j},f(i,j)},...}}}`. In my actual data the relationship between `f(i,j)` and `j,i` is unknown and the goal is to get an estimated `f(i,j)`.

Example data:

```
list = Flatten[
  Table[{{i + 0.1 Random[], j + 0.1 Random[]}, 10*i*j + Random[]}, {i,
     0, 1, 0.1}, {j, 0, 1, 0.1}], 1]
```

How do I find a good estimation of `f(i,j)`?
As a bonus, I would like to find an interpolating function that can predict `f(i,j)` for intermediate values of `i,j` not present in the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a model for $f$ then you'd go down the fitting route with `NonlinearModelFit`, or you could fit a plane with [`ResourceFunction["PlaneOfBestFit"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PlaneOfBestFit). However, you could also use `Predict` here as I will show below:

```
pf = Predict[Rule @@@ list, Method -> "NeuralNetwork"];
Show[
 Plot3D[pf[{x, y}], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.25]],
 ListPointPlot3D[Flatten /@ list]
]
```

[image: predict plot]

---

Using `Method->"GaussianProcess"` also produces a good fit. If you have a lot of data, it is important to avoid over-fitting. We can divide the data into a training set and a validation set in a 70% to 30% ratio by random sample, and we can use the validation data to ensure the predictor isn't over-fitting the data [(see cross-validation)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)).

```
list = Flatten[
   Table[{{i + 0.1 Random[], j + 0.1 Random[]}, 
     10*i*j + Random[]}, {i, 0, 1, 0.05}, {j, 0, 1, 0.05}], 1];

(* divide the data into 70% training and 30% cross-validation *) 
{training, validation} = 
  TakeDrop[#, Round[Length[#]*0.7]] &@RandomSample[Rule @@@ list];

pf = Predict[training, Method -> "GaussianProcess", 
   ValidationSet -> validation];

Show[
 Plot3D[pf[{x, y}], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.25]],
 ListPointPlot3D[Flatten /@ list]
 ]
pm = PredictorMeasurements[pf, validation];
pm["RSquared"]
pm["ComparisonPlot"]
```

By using `PredictorMeasurements` on the validation set, we can gauge how well the fit is generalizing to unseen data:

[image: comparison plot predict]

Comment: You can use `pf[{x,y}]` to get intermediate values. Note you can change the `Method`  to something else. If you use `Method->"LinearRegression"` you'll get a plane in the plot. Try `Method->"GaussianProcess"` - it produces a good fit too. The other methods are more jumpy.

Comment: thanks a lot! One question: With Mathematica 12.0 I get following error message with my data:PredictorMeasurementsObject::mlnaseth: "RSquared" is not an available property. Did you mean "MeanSquare" instead?

Comment: It's in 12.1 - I think it was a new feature.